# ASP .NET: CustomValidator doesn't launch its ServerValidate method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebApplication.MyWebForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 334px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 338px">

        <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="MyCustomValidator" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" ErrorMessage="My error message" 
            onservervalidate="Foo2"></asp:CustomValidator>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public partial class MyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        bool Foo1(string bar)
        {
            if (bar == "bar")
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        protected void Foo2(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            args.IsValid = this.Foo1(this.MyTextBox.Text);
        } // breakpoint
    }
}
```

I set breakpoint in the Foo2 function (comment), but debugger hasn't visited it. I tried writing diffrent text, not writting anything and writting "bar" and pushing enter and tab after that, but it still doesn't work. I mean text changing action. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no submit button. You need to add a button to submit the form, which will then trigger page validation.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="myButton" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: But I would prefer get reaction for an text changing action. Is it possible?

Comment: So you want every keystroke in the textbox to trigger a server roundtrip for validation? Not a good idea. It would be better to do your validation on the client-side with some javascript.